# Google OR-Tools Build (v9.2) unsuccessful from source

Tags: c++, cmake, or-tools

**Version of OR-Tools and language:** Version: v9.2, Language: C++, Python

**Solvers want to use:**
SCIP, CPLEX

**Operating system (Linux, Windows, ...) and version:**
ubuntu:16.04

**CMake version:** cmake-3.19.1

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

```
 wget https://github.com/google/or-tools/archive/refs/tags/v9.2.tar.gz
 tar xvf v9.2.tar.gz
 cd or-tools-9.2
 cmake -S. -Bbuild -DBUILD_GLOP:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_SCIP:BOOL=ON -DUSE_CPLEX:BOOL=ON -DCPLEX_ROOT=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/ -DBUILD_PYTHON:BOOL=ON -DPython3_ROOT_DIR=/opt/Python/Python3.10.1/
 cmake --build build
```

**Logs:**

```
[ 32%] Building CXX object ortools/util/CMakeFiles/ortools_util.dir/file_util.cc.o
In file included from /home/Projects/softwares/or-tools-9.2/ortools/util/file_util.cc:26:0:
/home/Projects/softwares/or-tools-9.2/ortools/util/file_util.cc: In function 'absl::lts_20211102::StatusOr<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > operations_research::ReadFileToString(absl::lts_20211102::string_view)':
/home/Projects/softwares/or-tools-9.2/ortools/base/status_macros.h:33:45: error: expected ')' before ';' token
     if (const ::absl::Status status = (expr); status.ok()) { \
                                             ^
/home/Projects/softwares/or-tools-9.2/ortools/util/file_util.cc:36:3: note: in expansion of macro 'RETURN_IF_ERROR'
   RETURN_IF_ERROR(file::GetContents(filename, &contents, file::Defaults()));
   ^
/home/Projects/softwares/or-tools-9.2/ortools/base/status_macros.h:33:45: error: could not convert 'status' from 'const absl::lts_20211102::Status' to 'bool'
     if (const ::absl::Status status = (expr); status.ok()) { \
                                             ^
/home/Projects/softwares/or-tools-9.2/ortools/util/file_util.cc:36:3: note: in expansion of macro 'RETURN_IF_ERROR'
   RETURN_IF_ERROR(file::GetContents(filename, &contents, file::Defaults()));
   ^
/home/Projects/softwares/or-tools-9.2/ortools/base/status_macros.h:33:47: error: 'status' was not declared in this scope
     if (const ::absl::Status status = (expr); status.ok()) { \
                                               ^
/home/Projects/softwares/or-tools-9.2/ortools/util/file_util.cc:36:3: note: in expansion of macro 'RETURN_IF_ERROR'
   RETURN_IF_ERROR(file::GetContents(filename, &contents, file::Defaults()));
   ^
/home/Projects/softwares/or-tools-9.2/ortools/base/status_macros.h:34:7: error: 'else' without a previous 'if'
     } else /* NOLINT */                                      \
       ^
/home/Projects/softwares/or-tools-9.2/ortools/util/file_util.cc:36:3: note: in expansion of macro 'RETURN_IF_ERROR'
   RETURN_IF_ERROR(file::GetContents(filename, &contents, file::Defaults()));
   ^
ortools/util/CMakeFiles/ortools_util.dir/build.make:107: recipe for target 'ortools/util/CMakeFiles/ortools_util.dir/file_util.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [ortools/util/CMakeFiles/ortools_util.dir/file_util.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5969: recipe for target 'ortools/util/CMakeFiles/ortools_util.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ortools/util/CMakeFiles/ortools_util.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:181: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Want to install OR-Tools for c++ and python that can use SCIP and CPLEX.

What I'm doing wrong here (all dependencies are installed)?

Additionally, want to know what will be the default install location and how to change that (-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install will this work)?

**Update 1:**

Previously gcc/g++ --version was 5.4, now after upgrading to gcc/g++ --version 9.4.
The following errors occurred! (CPLEX not yet supported on Linux!!!). This is for v9.1 (or-tools).

```
[ 87%] No test step for 'cbc-populate'
[100%] Completed 'cbc-populate'
[100%] Built target cbc-populate
--   AC_INIT: AC_INIT([Cbc],[2.10],[cbc@lists.coin-or.org])
--   version: 2.10.0
--   Use zlib
--   Found isfinite: std::isfinite
--   Found isnan: std::isnan
--   Found int64_t: int64_t
--   Found uint64_t: uint64_t
--   Found intptr_t: intptr_t
-- Fetching Cbc - fetched
-- Found long size: 8
-- Found long long size: 8
-- Found int64_t size: 8
-- Found unsigned long size: 8
-- Found unsigned long long size: 8
-- Found uint64_t size: 8
-- Found int * size: 8
CMake Error at cmake/FindCPLEX.cmake:43 (message):
  CPLEX not yet supported on Linux
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/deps.cmake:83 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:246 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

**Update 2**

Commands:

```
cmake -S. -Bbuild -DBUILD_GLOP:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_SCIP:BOOL=ON -DUSE_CPLEX:BOOL=ON -DCPLEX_ROOT=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/ -DBUILD_PYTHON:BOOL=ON -DPython3_ROOT_DIR=/opt/Python/Python3.10.1/ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/google/or-tools/v9.2
cmake --build build
```

The following errors occurred with v9.2 (or-tools).

```
[ 79%] Built target ortools_sat
Scanning dependencies of target ortools_scheduling
[ 79%] Building CXX object ortools/scheduling/CMakeFiles/ortools_scheduling.dir/jobshop_scheduling_parser.cc.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object ortools/scheduling/CMakeFiles/ortools_scheduling.dir/rcpsp_parser.cc.o
[ 79%] Built target ortools_scheduling
CMakeFiles/ortools.dir/build.make:601: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2167: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ortools.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ortools.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:181: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Update 3**

```
cmake -S. -Bbuild -DBUILD_DEPS:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_GLOP:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_SCIP:BOOL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/google/or-tools/v9.2
cmake --build build --config Release --target install -v
```

This builds without error and installed at `/opt/google/or-tools/v9.2`.

Now, how to use it in a CMake Project?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project (hello)
add_definitions("-std=c++17")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/google/or-tools/v9.2/")
find_package(ortools CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(hello main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello ortools::ortools)
```

**Update 4**

The following commands does not work.

```
cmake -S. -Bbuild -DBUILD_DEPS:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_GLOP:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_SCIP:BOOL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/google/or-tools/v9.2 -DUSE_CPLEX:BOOL=ON -DCPLEX_ROOT=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/
cmake --build build --config Release --target install -v
```

or

```
cmake -S. -Bbuild -DBUILD_DEPS:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_GLOP:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_SCIP:BOOL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/google/or-tools/v9.2 -DBUILD_PYTHON:BOOL=ON -DPython3_ROOT_DIR=/opt/Python/Python3.10.1/ 
cmake --build build --config Release --target install -v
```

Comment: C++17 is required. What is your compiler?

Comment: And support for Ubuntu 16.04 has been dropped.

Comment: `g++ --version` is 5.4.0 20160609. Let me try with latest g++ version.

Comment: and avoid cross posting without cross reference we are human... `-_-`
ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/3036

Comment: Sure. I thought so is more active after posting it there.

Comment: @Mizux I updated this post only as github issue was closed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't have any CPLEX license to test and there is no community developers strongly engage to help for the support of CPLEX on Linux BUT you can help us by providing a PR !

Basically you'll need to fix/rewrite https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/2cb85b4eead4c38e1c54b48044f92087cf165bce/cmake/FindCPLEX.cmake#L63-L73

```
  if(APPLE) # be aware that `UNIX` is `TRUE` on OS X, so this check must be first
    # FIXME(mizux) need actual macOS library path
    # target_link_libraries(CPLEX::CPLEX INTERFACE "${CPLEX_ROOT}/cplex/lib/libcplex.lib")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CPLEX not yet supported for CMake builds on ${CMAKE_SYSTEM}")
  elseif(UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(CPLEX::CPLEX INTERFACE "${CPLEX_ROOT}/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a")
  elseif(MSVC)
    target_link_libraries(CPLEX::CPLEX INTERFACE "${CPLEX_ROOT}/cplex/lib/x64_windows_msvc14/stat_mda/cplex12100.lib")
  else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CPLEX not supported for ${CMAKE_SYSTEM}")
  endif()
```

What is strange, is the message you get, are you sure to have tested against v9.2 or stable ?

This message recall me the v9.1 implementation...

```
if(APPLE)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CPLEX not yet supported on macOS")
elseif(UNIX)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CPLEX not yet supported on Linux")
endif()
```

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/v9.1/cmake/FindCPLEX.cmake#L40-L44

Comment: Thank you for your support. Indeed I checked out a different branch while testing. I updated the post accordingly. CPLEX has a free community license, that actually I'm using currently for testing small models (restricted to 1000 vars and 1000 constraints).